# Automate Store Sales Direct Conversions import to Google Ads using API

Tags: python-3.x, google-ads-api

I am currently importing conversions (Store Sales Direct Conversion) into Google Ads using UI on every month.
I am creating data to import to Google Ads in CSV format and then upload it using UI.
Current Method: Google Ads > Conversions > Uploads

I need to automate this process using Google Ads API and its Python module. 
How can I get this done?
What are the steps required to complete this job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Google Adwords API OfflineDataUploadService (v201809).
https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201809/OfflineDataUploadService

Before that you need to configure Adwords client and setup the authentication.

You would need below details to do the setup.

- Client ID
- Client Secret
- Refresh token
- Developer token
- user_agent
- client_customer_id

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/authentication

https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/first-call/dev-token

You need to create googleads.yaml config file and store the credentials for setup of authentication.
https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/blob/master/googleads.yaml

Refer the code below to create API calls

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/blob/master/examples/adwords/v201809/remarketing/upload_offline_data.py

**Note**: This service is available only on a whitelist basis.